# Jquery load more content on scroll ,sometimes don't execute javascripts

Tags: jquery, ajax

my site is gapagap.com and when i scroll down through posts it loads more posts,but there is a function "vote" in it which on click sometimes work for some post and sometimes not work for random post.
here is the code snippet..

**INDEX.php**

```
       <div id="entries-content" class="list">
            <ul id="entries-content-ul" class="col-1">
                {section name=i loop=$posts}
                {include file="posts_bit.tpl"}
                {/section}   
                      {literal}
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
      //calling header function to set the active tab state
      headerTabChange('hot');

                var tpage = 2;
                function lastAddedLiveFunc()
                {

                                      $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('');
                    $.get("{/literal}{$baseurl}/{literal}indexmore.php?page="+tpage, function(data){
                        if (data != "") {

                                            $(".col-1").append(data);

                        }
                        $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
                    });
                };

                $(window).scroll(function(){

                    var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
                    var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

                    if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
                     lastAddedLiveFunc();
                     tpage = tpage+1;
                     $('#backtotop').show();
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
            {/literal}     

              </ul>
            <div id="lastPostsLoader"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>

      {include file='right.tpl'}
      {include file='vote_js.tpl'}
```

**here is code for vote_js.tpl:**

```
    {literal}
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.vote').click(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('loved')){
        $(this).removeClass('loved');
        likedeg(-1,$(this).attr('rel'));
        }else{
        likedeg(1,$(this).attr('rel'));
         $(this).addClass('loved');
        }
        });
        function likedeg(x,p){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{/literal}{$baseurl}{literal}'+ '/likedeg.php',
        data:'art='+x+'&pid=' + p,
        success:function(e){
            $('#love_count_'+p).html(e);
            }
        });
         }
        </script>
    {/literal}
```

here is another code that has vote function in **post.tpl**

```
   <li>
    {if $smarty.session.USERID ne ""}

   <a class="vote love {insert name=get_fav_class value=var PID=$posts[i].PID}" id="post_love_{$posts[i].PID}" rel="{$posts[i].PID}" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>{$lang144}</span></a>
      {else}
     <a class="vote love " id="post_love_{$posts[i].PID}" rel="{$posts[i].PID}" href="{$baseurl}/login"><span>{$lang144}</span></a>
       {/if}
      </li>
```

**vote function is inside function.php**

```
       function insert_get_fav_status($var)
       {
              global $conn;
          $query="SELECT count(*) as total FROM posts_favorited WHERE                   USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[USERID])."' AND PID='".intval($var[PID])."'";
          $executequery=$conn->execute($query);
$total = $executequery->fields[total];
//echo $total.'<br />';
//var_dump($var);
return intval($total);
        }

         function insert_get_fav_class($var)
             {
               global $conn;
                $query="SELECT count(*) as total FROM posts_favorited WHERE  USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[USERID])."' AND PID='".intval($var[PID])."'";
               $executequery=$conn->execute($query);
               $total = $executequery->fields[total];
                  //echo $total.'<br />';
                 //var_dump($var);
                if (intval($total) == 1) return("loved");
                 else return ("");
               }

             function insert_get_unfav_status($var)
             {
              global $conn;
                $query="SELECT count(*) as total FROM posts_unfavorited WHERE  USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[USERID])."' AND PID='".intval($var[PID])."'";
           $executequery=$conn->execute($query);
           $total = $executequery->fields[total];
          return intval($total);
                }

                function insert_get_fav_count($var)
                {
                 global $conn;
             $query="SELECT count(*) as total FROM posts_favorited WHERE                           PID='".intval($var[PID])."'";
          $executequery=$conn->execute($query);
          $total = $executequery->fields[total];
         return intval($total);
                }
```

**PLEASE UNDERSTAND I AM A PHP DEVELOPER.I HAVE ZERO KNOWLEDGE IN JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY.**

Comment: I don't see any code about a `vote` function. Can you be more specific / post more details ?

Comment: yup because vote func is workin very fine for the ist page the problem is when more content loads using the above function.The problem is javascript is not loading properly.

Comment: Show how `vote` is bound to `click`

Comment: Please you should add more detail into your question. First you have to specify the output that you got from $.get, second, you said sometimes it does not work, so what result do you expect? You told you have no idea about javascript, but you know even jQuery or still nothing about it?

Comment: "snippet". I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @allyourcode from thousand lines of codes,i have selected these few necessary lines to make my question appear clear.So i called it SNIPPET

Comment: @LeGEC ok now i have added all the neccessary codes.please have a look and please suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question again.....but frankly i don't wanna change this habit..lol.

there in place of

`{ $(".col-1").append(data);`

i replaced it with  `{ $(".col-1").html(html()+data);`

thanks all of you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get("{/literal}{$baseurl}/{literal}indexmore.php?page="+tpage).done(function(data) {
    if (data != "") {
        $(".col-1").append(data);
    }
    $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function (d, buildThese) {
   var homeScript, newScript, n = buildThese.length, i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
     newScript = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
     newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newScript.async = true;
     newScript.src = buildThese[i];
     homeScript = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
     homeScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, homeScript);
  }
});
</script>
```

You do realize that you're currently invoking this closure:

- **Before your elements are even fully inserted in the DOM**
- **Without any arguments (try it: in this specific function, both d and buildThese are *undefined* )**
- Without checking

The two bolded reasons are what are causing your code to screw up. If you do not have anything in there, buildThese will be undefined and its length will be 0. Therefore, the loop will never run. Even if it did, d is undefined, and so you'd get a fatal error on d.createElement.

The function you want is jQuery **done()**. This clever little function allows you to set a callback that will trigger when all the new elements are inserted. It works like this:

```
$.get("myURL").done(function() { alert("I'm done!"); });
```

This will also have two unintended effects to your code:

- It will allow you to not have duplicates of the Twitter API script every time you load a new page
- It will allow you to **ONLY** GET HTML and to therefore keep your JS in one place.

Comment: Renauld   As i mentioned i dont hve ne idea about javascript,thats the code i pasted in my index.tpl file.So i request you to please tell me in reference to that ...shud i include this buildthese() func in my index???and whats this `$.get("myURL").done(function() { alert("I'm done!"); });`  shud i add this too??

Comment: Strip out the buildThese code, throw it in the function inside `done` and *make sure to pass parameters to it*. If you don't get either of the three, go to the jQuery doc at http://jquery.com/ and search for .ajax().
(If you don't have a clue about JS, modifying asynchronous JS is probably not the best first step...especially without reading anything about it first)

Comment: did't work::`$.get("{/literal}{$baseurl}/{literal}indexmore.php?page="+tpage).done(function(data) {
    if (data != "") {
        $(".col-1").append(data);
    }
    $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
});`